# Bash script to end and edit Typescript file at the end of terminal session automatically

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm using the script command to record my terminal activity. 
After the session closes, I'm using the following command to process the 
resultant Typescript file:

```
cat typescript | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b > typescript-processed
```

Now, the command to begin the recording and the command above are present in the same bash file. Is it possible to invoke the above code segment (running in background at that time) only when the terminal session is being closed?

Thanks in advance! •ᴗ•

Comment: You may be able to *trap* the relevant signal in the shell - see for example Gilles' answer here [Are any files loaded when a terminal session terminates?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58349/65304)

Answer (score 0):

Try this place that script in the `~/.bash_logout` file and when the shell closes it will be run.

I used this example and it worked:

```bsh
finish() {

        echo "my firstname" >> /tmp/kokolet
}
trap finish EXIT
```